# Why are LaTeX macros so inconsistent?

Tags: macros

I use LaTeX daily to write my papers, and while I find it a very nice tool to make documents in, some things about the system outright bother me; such as the very inconsistent macro system.

A few examples:

Many, but not all block macros/commands look like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

except for math blocks which look like this:

```
\[ ... \]
```

Inline macros usually look like this:

```
\footnote{...}
```

Except when they suddenly look like this:

```
{\em ...} % I'm aware that \emph{...} also exits
```

Or like this:

```
\lstinline|...|
```

Or even like this:

```
$ ... $
```

So why is it that LaTeX is so inconsistently designed? It seems that for every package I add, there's a new way of writing it, which makes the learning curve of LaTeX insanely steep, why not just keep it all consistent and uniform?

Comment: Instead of `\[` and `\]` you can use `\begin{displaymath}` and `\end{displaymath}`. Instead of `{\em ...}` you can use `\emph{...}`. Instead of `$...$` you can use `\begin{math}...\end{math}`.

Comment: The lack of uniformity in verbatim-like inline commands is a necessary feature: it allows you to determine the delimiter of the verbatim content yourself so you can use a delim that is not contained in the content.

Comment: I don't think there is inconsistency. Each construct serves its purposes, although some of them should not be used any longer, e.g. `$$....$$`. For example, an environment is pretty good for some 'cleanup' at the end

Comment: yeah but you gotta admit `\lstinline|...|` just makes no sense, when it could just as easily have been `\lstinline{...}`

Comment: I think a bigger bigger disconnect can be felt by comparing packages/classes that offer a key-val interface and packages/classes that don't. An example: `beamer` vs `moderncv`

Comment: @ElectricCoffee `\lstinline|\textbf{...}|`. I(n this case the use of `|...|` makes this a lot easier to read (at source level) than `\lstinline{\textbf{...}}`.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee see my comment on verbatim-like commands. lstinline is one of them

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: The multitude of features of some commands needs varying interfaces

Comment: @Bordaigorl: I agree especially with your statement about the key-val interfaces for classes. Some classes are really annoying and hard to configure

Comment: How would you display a verbatim `}`? `\lstinline{}}` would be a syntax error.

Comment: One thing that you've got to watch is the difference between LaTeX kernel syntax (as David says, pretty consistent) and what package authors add on, some of which can be rather different. If/when the team finish LaTeX3 we can expect a much stronger position on what syntaxes packages should/should not offer.

Comment: Note that a few of the cases you highlight are there because for some common tasks a 'shortcut' is useful. For example, as @HeikoOberdiek says you _can_ use a more verbose syntax for display math, but it would get pretty tiring in practice.

Comment: "So why is it that LaTeX is so inconsistently designed?" -- *has* it been designed? Arguably, a system that can rewrite its own lexer and has no (enforced/-able) standards and few conventions (as far as I can tell) can hardly be called "designed", as far as syntax goes.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One of the main aims of LaTeX is to give a *consistent*  syntax over the wildly inconsistent syntax of the TeX primitives, so

`\frac{a}{b}` not `{a \over b}`

`\makebox[3pt]{foo}` not `\hbox to 3pt{foo}`

`\begin{math} x \end{math}` as an alias for `$ x $`

The distinction between environments and commands with arguments is slightly arbitrary but generally works reasonably well, using an environment body for large chunks of text. You see similar things in most document markup systems, e.g. the distinction between attributes and elements in HTML or XML `<p> xxx </p>` but `href=....`

Most two letter font commands (`\bf` etc) have been deprecated, partly for this reason since LaTeX2e was released. (`\em` is a bit different as noted in comments.)

Your other examples related to listings and verbatim, they necessarily have a different syntax, compare XML where the similar construct isn't an element or an attribute but `<![CDATA[....]]>`

Comment: Erm, `\em` isn't deprecated (uniquely amongst the two-letter font change commands)

Comment: @JosephWright : Is there a good reason for that? Otherwise, maybe it could be (informally) deprecated just for consistency?

Comment: @T.Verron `\em` isn't the same as `\textit`: it does the 'emphasis on and off' business for nesting correctly. Try `{\em Some {\em text}}` and contrast `{\textit Some {\textit text}}`. It's _not_ just a command to make stuff italic.

Comment: @T.Verron In addition to Joseph's comment, there's no alternative declaration to `\em`. (`\bf` should be replaced with `\bfseries`, `\it` should be replaced with `\itshape`, etc.) With emphasis, you only have a choice of the text-block command `\emph{text}` or the declaration `\em`.

Comment: @JosephWright true but `\textit` can be compared with `\emph` Nicola's probably correct that we didn't deprecate `\em` as there is no `\emshape` (I'lledit the answer anyway)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but that's because it's not actually a shape or anything: it's a flexible higher-level concept ('do something to make this stand out'). I'm not sure there is a better name than `\em`: it's just unfortunate that it looks like other two-letter commands.

Comment: @T.Verron the symmetries within latex _are_ there, but they're sometimes tricky to spot.  not “higgs boson” tricky, but “study everything in enormous detail before trying to give an answer” tricky.  believe me, a lot of the stuff described in these comments was simply “not there” before the advent of latex2e in 1994.

Comment: @wasteofspace Hem... sure, but what's your point?

Comment: @JosephWright yes name \emshape made up name on spot, `\declarativeswitchformofemph` perhaps.

Comment: @wasteofspace - My pre-1994 cell phone was a big huge brick. It didn't have many features and was a bit hard to use. My pre-1994 computers were also big huge bricks. They didn't have many features and were also a bit hard to use.

Comment: That's all very true, however none of this is actually enforced. Afaic, there isn't even a flag for, say, `pdflatex` that warns about any old/deprecated macro usage. And then you open the doc of `xparse` and see that you can declare anything a parameter delimiter...

Comment: @Raphael sure it's a macro expansion language: nothing is enforced and the full implementation of every command is visible, and changeable, at runtime. That doesn't mean one shouldn't try to develop and encourage some consistent syntax guidelines.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to David Carlisle's answer, I would quote the Zen of Python on this one:

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity.

As David pointed out, there are ways to write these commands in a standard style. But if I'm writing a paper, I don't want it to be littered with

```
Then substitute
\begin{math}
  x^2
\end{math}
for
\begin{math}
  y
\end{math}
in \ref{eq:foo}.
```

when

```
Then substitute $x^2$ for $y$ in \ref{eq:foo}.
```

would suffice.

This is one major case where practicality breaks purity. Sure, the first version is purer. But the purity is simply not worth it.

Comment: And we pay for it with often useless error messages -- extra/missing $ is a particular pain in the ass.

Comment: @Raphael — If you want (slightly) better error messages, use `\(...\)` instead of `$...$`.

Comment: @WillRobertson: Yup, those enable more robust matching. Unfortunately, they are a pain to type -- there's a trade-off for you.

Comment: I would go as far as to say that if you care about purity that much to write a document in the first style, then go all the way and use XML as an input format. That has an additional advantage that you can easily verify that the input conforms to a schema

Comment: @Aditya right, like in iTeX!

Comment: You probably want `\eqref{}` for references to equations.

Comment: @David in practice yes, but `\eqref` is part of amsmath, so for MWE purposes I left it out.

Comment: @Raphael an advantage of `\( \)` is editor support. For example, vim lets you jump from one to the other with `%`, which is not the case with `$`.

Answer (score 9):

Without getting into a discussion about which syntax is how useful, reasonable and established, there is one fundamental reason.

(La)TeX does not *have* a (static) syntax. The lexer may be redefined at any point during interpretation, even by the end user (i.e. in document code).

That enables every package and document author to develop their own syntax, however clever or ill-advised. Come a few decades of (re)development, you are stuck with buckloads of (legacy) stuff, barely cobbled together by a few brave conventions.

Comment: After a while, one understands the syntax of LaTeX itself, and it even begins to make sense.  However, you always need several packages to do what you want, and that's really when things get ugly.  ConTeXt does a much better job in this respect, and usually needs no external packages.  I committed myself to ConTeXt for a year, but gave it up because no one else in math/science uses it.  LaTeX was amazing when it was new, and is still amazing today.  It really needs an overhaul.  But given the huge user base, a change in the "API" would be a difficult sell.